# Search for a file in GIT history?

Tags: git, git-history

So there was a file in one of my projects which was deleted, no one knows when or why, it's just gonne. (a few months probably). Problem is i only know a part of the name, not the full name. How can i search the files added/removed in commits (not commit message) for this?

The file should look like `something_something.*.xml`, any ideas? [the * can be a string, or multiple string separated by underscore, dash or dot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do
`git log --all --full-history -- **/theFile.*`

Comment: try using  a relative path rather than absolute path

Comment: If it's possible for the file to be in the root, then they may need to also have `theFile.*` as a separate pathspec; in my tests `**/theFile.*` misses this case.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: `**/` is intended to match the root as well, so I'd suggest reporting a bug. Of course if you do have the bug, use `'**/*remembered_part*' '*remembered_part*'` to work around it, yes.

Comment: At least in git version `2.39.2` on Apple. The pattern matching in filename won't work without double quotes. This command works: `git log --all --full-history -- "**/theFile.*" `

Comment: I am running git v 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143) on a M2. I don't need quotes. #works-on-my-machine